# SQL: how to have a conditional output in one statement

Tags: sql

**Table person**

```
id | name | age
---------------
1  | max  | 30
2  | sue  | 28
3  | ada  | 22
4  | sam  | 31
5  | test | 0
```

**Table male**

```
id  | personid
--------------
1   | 1
2   | 4
3   | 5
```

**Table female**

```
id  | personid
--------------
1   | 2
2   | 3
3   | 5
```

How can I get an output like this? So a column (gender) should be related to the presence in another table and the output.

```
name | gender
-------------
max  | M
sue  | F
ada  | F
sam  | M
test | X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE statement to look up from the gender tables as:

```
SELECT a.name, 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT personid FROM TableMale b WHERE b.personid = a.ID) THEN 'M' 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT personid FROM TableFemale c WHERE c.personid = a.ID) THEN 'F' 
  END AS Gender  
FROM TablePerson a
```

Comment: @chris01 . . . You accepted this answer and it does not return `'X'`.  It does not correctly answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with nested IIF statements:

```
SELECT p.[Name], IIF(m.ID IS NOT NULL AND f.ID IS NOT NULL, 'X', IIF(m.ID IS NOT NULL, 'M', 'F')) AS Gender
FROM Person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Male m ON p.ID = m.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Female f ON p.ID = f.PersonID
```

Answer (score 1):

Personid 5 is both male and female.  I would not want to lose this information.  So:

```
select p.name,
       (case when m.personid is not null and f.personid is not null
             then 'X'  -- both
             when m.personid is not null
             then 'M'
             when f.personid is not null
             then 'F'
        end) as gender
from person p left join
     male m
     on p.id = m.personid left join
     female f
     on p.id = f.personid;
```